# Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Unable to make field private

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to update java version from 15 to 17 in my spring boot application but getting error ": Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Unable to make field private". Does anyone know how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: you provide way to little of your context for us to begin even guess

Comment: are you using lombok ? it can be related to that also.

Comment: @muhammedozbilici I have updated the lombok versoin to latest (1.8.24)but still getting this error.

Comment: @AnujSharma do clean install and maybe intellij (if you are using), invalidate cache restart.

Comment: @muhammedozbilici I have done that but not working  it is also failing in Jenkins build pipeline as well with the same error.